# Comparing char in string with pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("test.rpn", "r");
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if(&line[0] == "#"){
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, the first character of a line is # and yet it is not exiting.  I have also tried 0/1/2/3/4 just to see if it was so weird start of line issue but it is not.

Answer (score 4):

Instead do this

```
if (line[0] == '#') // Note the single quotes
```

When you take the address surely the comparison is false regardless of what character is at `line[0]` because you are comparing addresses<sup>1</sup> and you can be certain that they will be different. You instead need to compare the values.

Also, when you see a warning it usually means that something is wrong. If you see a warning and yet nothing is wrong then you surely were expecting such warning. If the warning is unexpected, you did something bad.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>`&line[0]` is the same as `line` so you are comparing the address of `line` which is a pointer to the address of the string literal `"#"` which with all certainty **is not the same**.</sub>

Comment: I have tried that, it does not work either, and I get a warning "main.c:63:30: warning: comparison between pointer and integer"

Comment: @asdqq Please not the single quotes, `'#'` and enable compilation warnings. You either 1. Didn't try that! 2. Your input does not have a `#` as the first character.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that and using '#' instead of "#" solved my problem.  The issue was with the '&', i didn't notice you changed that as well, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(&line[0] == "#"){
```

should be

```
if(line[0] == '#'){
```

You want to compare the first character of the string and `line` is already a string, there is no need to take the address of (`&`), also use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: `'#'` is probably the intent, not `"#"`.

Comment: I have tried that, it does not work either, and I get a warning "main.c:63:30: warning: comparison between pointer and integer"

Comment: Thank you @DeiDei , that and not using "&" solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`&line` means the address of the line, you want his value and therefore use :

```
line[0] == '#'
```